# .NET Copy Third Party Libraries to Bin\Release

Tags: .net, visual-studio, deployment

We use Microsoft Smart client, Enterprise Library, Composite Application Block and Infragistics and some more third party libraries.

In the project, we added references to the libraries in the Visual Studio 'Add Reference' and selecting from .NET component lists.

How to make sure all the DLLs shall be copied to the deployment directory when we need to give these files for customer where they don't install all the libraries mentioned above?

Regards,

Krish

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume you have set the "Copy Local" property on the reference to True.

To automatically copy files after a build, modify the "Post-build event command line" found in the project properties. Insert the appropriate command to copy your files.

Answer (score 0):

If they are all references, just select them and set 'Copy Local' to true in the PropertyGrid.

Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/304909/best-practices-for-referencing-3rd-party-assemblies) question too.