# Which files to include in the download package when publishing a program through VS2010?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, c#-4.0, publish

I have made a program in VS2010, written in C#. It uses extra libraries and databases.

My teacher wanted to test it a few days ago, so I had sent him the setup file which publishing the project created. This setup didn't work because there were "files missing".

I then just sent him the whole published map.

Which files do I need to include for a published program to install and work on another pc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on several things. Usually the contents of the bin\debug or bin\release should be sufficient providing your teacher has the same version of .Net installed. One thing it depends greatly on is whether or not you are using any libraries outside the core .Net. If not, then the bin directory should be sufficient. If you are using third party libraries and those libraries are GAC'ed on your machine then VS will not copy them to the bin directories.

This is a very similar question: [Dependencies and references - What exactly should I reference?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/268214/dependencies-and-references-what-exactly-should-i-reference)